# SAML 2.0 Digest Value Calculation in SAML Assertion

Tags: security, saml, sha256, okta, message-digest

I want to know how digestValue was calculated when we have AttributeStatement in the SAML 2 Response.
I can calculate and get the same digestValue when I do not have any "saml2:AttributeStatement" returned in SAML response by:

1. Deleting ds:Signature segment
2. Canonicalizing XML payload
3. Applying SHA-256 to calculate digest value (as I configured on IDP part)

But when I configured in IDP side to add "saml2:AttributeStatement" in the response along with one attribute, I can no longer calculate the same digestvalue as IDP returned to me no matter I kept "saml2:AttributeStatement" or not.

What shall I do here to calculate the correct value? FYI, I am using OKTA IDP.

My SAML Assertion in my SAML response is as follows:

```
<saml2:Assertion ID="id2725281198079267683856882"
                     IssueInstant="2021-09-20T07:18:33.051Z"
                     Version="2.0"
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     >
    <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                      >http://www.okta.com/exk1mv3c9ke9u3tz25d7
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature
        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#id2725281198079267683856882">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="xs"
                            xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                                    />
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                    <ds:DigestValue>uHowdunaQ+0tDsHrEGgJFUWwd23L08Qubp9HFS2In2Q=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>S9YQNf7t...</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDq...
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <saml2:Subject
                xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
                <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">allen.li@gmail.com</saml2:NameID>
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                    <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="a3b3ff8jicf316993316069j03bdjfj"
                                               NotOnOrAfter="2021-09-20T07:23:33.051Z"
                                               Recipient="http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO"
                                               />
                </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2021-09-20T07:13:33.051Z"
                          NotOnOrAfter="2021-09-20T07:23:33.051Z"
                xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                          >
                <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                    <saml2:Audience>http://localhost:8080/saml/metadata</saml2:Audience>
                </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
            </saml2:Conditions>
            <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2021-09-20T07:18:33.051Z"
                              SessionIndex="a3b3ff8jicf316993316069j03bdjfj"
                xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                              >
                <saml2:AuthnContext>
                    <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
                </saml2:AuthnContext>
            </saml2:AuthnStatement>
            <saml2:AttributeStatement
                xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
                <saml2:Attribute Name="email"
                             NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                             >
                    <saml2:AttributeValue
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                      xsi:type="xs:string"
                                      >allen.li@gmail.com
                    </saml2:AttributeValue>
                </saml2:Attribute>
            </saml2:AttributeStatement>
        </saml2:Assertion>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. There is a gap between OKTA performing Canonicalization and what is provided in Java org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer.getInstance(String). In Java implementation they deleted namespace xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", but OKTA kept it. After I added this namespace in canonicalized SAML Assertion and calculated digest value, I got same value as OKTA.